# $A\leq B \leq C \implies B\leq A^{1-\alpha} C^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces, real-numbers

Let $A, B, C \in (0, \infty)$ such that $A\leq B \leq C.$

> Can we say  that $B\leq A^{1-\alpha} C^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $A=1$, $B=2$, $C=3$ and $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @MR: Thanks. I got it. But can you take look the [page no. 5](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~cek/Kenigrev1.pdf) first three lines? I am wondering, how the author  got the inequality? Do I have have to use some thing else?